# rails, binding of caller output behaving differently to view output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok, I'll do my absolute best to explain this. If I miss anything important let me know.

I am using this line of code to go through a list of stock. I've truncated it to make it more readable.

```
       - @candidates.each do |product| #the variable candidates goes through a module to list available products from the Product class
            .................
            - product.jobs.unconfirmed.on_date_interval(@job.delivery, @job.collection).each do |unconfirmed| 
               #unconfirmed and on_date_interval are scopes in the product class,      
               #displaying unconfirmed products that fall within the specified date range 
                ...........
                  -unconfirmed.job_products.each do |x|
                    -raise #this bring up Binding Of Caller to inspect code in the browser
                    = x.quantity
```

The problem is occurring in the last iteration.

```
 -unconfirmed.job_products.each do |x|
```

NB: as i typed this out I realised potential confusion might have arisen out of the name of scope `unconfirmed` and the variable in line 3. However I made the variable name unique but this hasn't stopped the error.

So using Binding of Caller to view the output I see the variable `'x.quantity'` correctly outputs

```
>> x.quantity
=> 3
```

However when in the actual view without Binding of Caller the output is different. It displays all the quantities of every product that matches variable `x` in each instance of the `product` variable... annoying. So if `unconfirmed` variable contains TWO instances, they display in each respective product correctly. But the `x.quantity` will display the TWO  quantities in each product.

All I want is for each product displayed its available quantity like the Binding of Caller output.

I haven't listed model relationships because they are rather complex (for me any way) and I didn't think they were related to the problem. If you think they might be just ask.

Cheers folks.

Comment: You don't actually state what the desired behavior is.  Do you want to display the *sum* of the quantities for all the job_projects?